# Riemann-Roch theorem on $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

here is my question :

let $K$ be a field and $X$ a projective regular curve over $spec (K)$. Denote by Let $g$ be the genus of $X$.
The Riemann-Roch theorem implies that for every divisor $D$ on $X$ such that $\deg(D) > 2g-2$, we have :
$$ \dim_K(H^0(X,D)) = \deg(D)+1-g $$

Now let consider the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ as a curve and $D$ a divisor on $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, do we have an analogue of this equality by replacing the dimension by the rank of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $H^0(\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}),D)$ ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ may be a smooth curve in a quite precise sense, but it is not projective!

Comment: I know, that's why I'm looking for an analogue of this theorem, in others words, can we expression the rank of the $ \mathbb{Z}$-module in function of the degree of the divisor $D$ ?

Comment: The $\Bbb{Z}$-module $H^0(\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}),D)$ is very concrete, what do you get with $D= \sum_{j=1}^J (p_j\Bbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: I would look at the group structure of $L(D+E)/L(E)$ in term of $D$ which is less trivial and translates better to $Spec(\Bbb{Z})$ than $\dim L(D)$ and make an analogy with affine varieties.

Comment: A cartier divisor can be viewed as a rational number $\dfrac{n}{m}$ and $H^0( \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}),D)$ is the $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by $\dfrac{n}{m}$ ?